# What tool can I use to create 2D polygons which outputs list of coordinates?

Tags: polygons

I would like a free point and click type tool where I can create simple 2D polygon shapes on a grid using a Cartesian coordinate system. Ideally, the points can be dragged once created, and can snap to grid positions. Most importantly, I need the tool to create a table of x,y coordinate pairs for each point.

The closest I've found is this:

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/basic-geo/basic-geo-coord-plane/polygons-in-the-coordinate-plane/e/drawing-polygons

It does everything I want, but it doesn't output the coordinate pairs. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/).  It is free and does all this easily.

Comment: Thanks. I'd checked this before, but only tested the Geometry Calculator, which doesn't have all the functions I needed. However, the Graphing Calculator does do everything I need.

Comment: Is there any way to copy all the points at once? It's a bit of a pain having to copy each coordinate pair one at a time.

Comment: Put a box round all the points with the mouse then right click and choose the menu item.